# Picasso won't load Google Static Map

Tags: android, picasso

I'm trying to load an static map using this url:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=43.137022,13.067162&zoom=16&size=600x400&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true&markers=color:blue|43.137022,13.067162
```

I'm doing it with Square's `Picasso`, but it fails to load.

With some tests I've to the conclusion that the char `|` is the one messing up Picasso. Any idea on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Have you tried manually URL-escaping that pipe character?

Comment: Something like `|` to `\|` ?

Comment: No, the URL-encoded version of `|` is `%7C`: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Picasso appears to expect a URL-encoded URL. This means that the values of form variables need to be URL-encoded, the way they would if this were a submitted HTML form.

Alphanumeric characters do not need escaping, which is why most of your URL is fine. However, the `markers` parameter contains special characters, particularly that `|`, which need to be converted into URL-encoded values.

If you were programmatically generating the URL by pieces, you might use [`URLEncoder` and `encode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to handle this conversion for you.